# Visual Studio Intellisense fails with message "Parsing document"

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

I have a solution that uses `VueJS` and `Razor Pages`.

The problem is that suddenly i lost the intellisense. As soon as VS tries to get the proposals i get a message `Parsing Document` which closes after some seconds but i am getting no proposals.

[image]

The same solution works on my second machine, having the same configuration.

I tried many proposals for options

The only difference is that i updated Visual Studio to 16.10 today and i think that i lost it afterwards. I haven't updated my second machine to 16.10.

I uninstalled VS completely and installed it again 3 times with no change.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the .vs folder and clear the component caches in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_fdf4b90f\ComponentModelCache`